# Django-channel trying to send message on a channel returns error send attribute doesn't exist

Tags: django, django-channels

I am receiving following error when calling django-channel object

```
Channel("websocket.receive").send({
    "room": message.channel_session['room'],
    "message": message['text'],
})
```

`AttributeError: 'Channel' object has no attribute 'send'`

here is the consumer function. The print message inside the function is getting printed

```
def ws_receive_in_music_channel(message,pk):

   print("received a message")
   payload = message.content['text']


   Channel("websocket.receive").send({
     "room": message.channel_session['room'],
     "message": message['text'],
   })
```

`routing.py`

channel_routing = [

```
route("websocket.connect",ws_connect, path=r'^/mychannels/$'),
route("websocket.connect",ws_connect_music_channel, path=r'^/mychannels/(?P<pk>\S+)/$'),

route("websocket.disconnect",ws_disconnect,path=r'^/mychannels/$'),
route("websocket.disconnect",ws_disconnect_music_channel,path=r'^/mychannels/(?P<pk>\S+)/$'),

route("websocket.receive",ws_receive,path=r'^/mychannels/$'),

route("websocket.receive",ws_receive_in_music_channel, path=r'^/mychannels/(?P<pk>\S+)/$'),

#route for share song in a channel
route("music_channel.share_song",share_song,command="^share$"),
```

]

Comment: did you try that inside a function? can you post the total function

Comment: @Exprator updated..the consumer function is getting called and "receieved a message is getting print"

Comment: have you added routing.py and registered your function?

Comment: I have added the consumer function to the routing but what do you mean by registering function? Please see the edit

Comment: check the answer and let me know

Comment: what decorator is wrapping that consumer?

Comment: @HassenPy No decorator as of now..

Comment: actually, the decorator doesn't matter in this case, does it work in the other consumer? how are you importing the `Channel` object?